# Execute bat file from powershell with administrative credentials?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to execute a batch file from powershell or command line, but it needs to execute with administrative credentials.

Is there a way to pass the administrative credentials as an argument in command line/powershell to execute batch file?
I tried to use -Credential new-object but it prompt the credentials popup on the screen

Comment: To answer your question. It is YES. But you can use the `runas` also. Show your code mate.

Comment: There are some cmdlets supporting the parameter -Credential but the actual challenge is to pass the credentials securely to the cmdlets.